# Realtime database. When I send a put request with date 0 (just the number 0), I get an error. Other numbers work

Tags: javascript, ajax, firebase-realtime-database, axios

There is a Firebase realtime database, and the anime likes function has been implemented on the website. The problems come from removing a like, it is implemented like this: a get request is made, the response contains the current number of likes and a put request is sent, setting the response to the get request minus 1.

Also, the user's information about this anime is removed from his data, but this is not so important.

```
async unlikeAnime(userID, likeID, animeID) {
    const likeCount = await firebase.get(`AnimeList/${animeID}/like.json`);
    firebase.put(`AnimeList/${animeID}/like.json`, parseInt(likeCount.data - 1));
    firebase.delete(`Users/${userID}/likedAnime/${likeID}.json`);
}
```

Everything works fine with any numbers except 0. If a new anime is added to the site (it is displayed in the database with 0 likes), and then the user likes it (sends 1 to the database), and then removes it (sends 0 to the database), then the database will give an error and will not remove the like.

[image]

[image]

I checked whether the same types of data were sent in all situations (yes, a number), checked whether the correct response was received from a get request when there was 1 like (yes, likeCount.date returns 1 and is sent 0). I even wrote ParseInt just in case, it doesn’t help.

The get request and delete request work 100% perfectly, the problem is only in the put and only if the data is equal to the number 0. It simply cannot set the number 0 in the database and returns an error.

I checked the quality of the request, it is being created correctly. The link is fully working and correct. And I’ll also attach a link to what the database looks like.
[image]

It is created with 0 likes, then the user puts 1 like and removes it, again setting 0. And an error comes.

[image]

Comment: Why are you using the REST API instead of the JavaScript SDK?

Comment: @Phil , I’m just learning and currently learning React, frontend, I just wanted to make a full-fledged project. I didn’t even understand your question, I just need to solve my problem in these circumstances, and not rewrite everything from scratch)

Comment: You're using the [Firebase REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database). It's more common to use the [Firebase JS SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) which is fully featured and type safe.

Comment: In any case, Firebase is probably telling you what the problem is. Check in the error's `response.data` property for details (the `response` object is towards the bottom of your first screenshot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error: "No data supplied."

I suspect this is caused by the literal `0` in the request body and the `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header. You might be able to work around it by enforcing `Content-Type: application/json` but there is a better way...

What you're trying to accomplish can be achieved much more easily using a [server value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-server-values).

> You can write server values at a location using a placeholder value which is an **object with a single `.sv` key**. The value for that key is the type of server value you wish to set.

Reading the value, decrementing it and sending the new value back to the database is not atomic and could lead to race conditions. Instead, tell the server to decrement the value for you using a negative `increment` server-value.

```js
firebase.put(`AnimeList/${animeID}/like.json`, { '.sv': { increment: -1 } });
```

See also [Atomic server-side increments](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#atomic_server-side_increments) for more detail on performing atomic server-side data manipulation.

Comment: Updated the question and added the date. How does your version of the code in the answer work?

Comment: What is it you need clarification on in my answer?

Comment: how work this code: { '.sv': { increment: -1 } });

Comment: Have you tried reading the links I provided?

Comment: ,Yes, it works! Thank you! But I still don’t understand what it means '.sv' and 'increment', please explain to the frontender xddd

Comment: It's quite literally explained in the first link I provided as well as the quoted section in my answer https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-server-values

Comment: thx so much!!!!